# C++: How to create a multiset of objects of a class?

Tags: c++, class, stl, multiset

Here is my class declaration:

```
class Person
{
private:
    string name;

public:
    void showData()
    {
        cout << name << endl;
    }
    void insertData()
    {
        cin >> name;
    }
    bool operator<(Person p)
    {
        return name < p.name;
    }
};
```

Now I am trying to create a multiset of objects of person class, How to do so?
Here is the main function which I to wrote:

```
int main()
{
    multiset<Person> m;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Person p;
        p.insertData();
        m.insert(p);
    }
    multiset<Person>::iterator it;
    // for (it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
    // {
    //    cout << it.name << endl;
    // }
}
```

Comment: If you compile with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), enable all warnings and debug info: use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use later [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your `operator<` in a slightly different way. I would define it as a friend not a class member, but if it is a class member it should be `const`.

So this is OK

```
class Person
{
    ...
    bool operator<(Person p) const
    {
        return name < p.name;
    }
};
```

but I would do it like this

```
class Person
{
    ...
    friend bool operator<(const Person& x, const Person& y)
    {
        return x.name < y.name;
    }
};
```

Comment: Even if it's not a friend the argument should still be a const reference. There's no reason to copy the object in order to perform a comparison.